# Extract ip and uag from Cloudflare cdn-cgi/trace text result using regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, ip, user-agent, cloudflare

Hi I am planning to use Cloudflare cdn-cgi trace service to get clients IP and User Agent results. If I fetch this link: `https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace`, the result I am getting is in a text format.
Result text example:

```
fl=47f54
h=www.cloudflare.com
ip=11.111.11.11
ts=1597428248.652
visit_scheme=https
uag=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
colo=OH
http=http/2
loc=US
tls=TLSv1.3
sni=plaintext
warp=off
```

I did some research and figured out I need to use Regex? But not sure how to extract only the ip and uag from the result.

```
...
ip=11.111.11.11
...
uag=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
...
```

How do I just extract the result `11.111.11.11` (ip changes for all client) and `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36` (uag or user agent changes for all client) from the above text for each result I fetch?

Comment: [**This**](https://regex101.com/r/KN9CEi/6) might help. Please do let me know if it helped?

Comment: Thanks this helped.

Comment: Does this cloudflare service to detect ip address is free without any limitations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try:

```
^(?:ip|uag)=(.*)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the line respectively.
- **`(?:ip|uag)`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching either `ip` or `uag` literally.
- **`=`** - Represents `=` literally.
- **`(.*)`** - Represents first caturing group matching anything zero or more time which is preceded by `ip=` or `uag=`.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/KN9CEi/9)

```js
const myRegexp = /^(?:ip|uag)=(.*)$/gm;
const myString = `fl=47f54
h=www.cloudflare.com
ip=11.111.11.11
ts=1597428248.652
visit_scheme=https
uag=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
colo=OH
http=http/2
loc=US
tls=TLSv1.3
sni=plaintext
warp=off`;
let match;

let resultString = "";
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
  resultString = resultString.concat(match[1] + "\n");
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
console.log(resultString);
```

---

**2nd approach:**

```js
const myString = `fl=47f54
h=www.cloudflare.com
ip=11.111.11.11
ts=1597428248.652
visit_scheme=https
uag=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
colo=OH
http=http/2
loc=US
tls=TLSv1.3
sni=plaintext
warp=off`;
// Split on new line filter on the condition that element starts with ip or uag and join
console.log(myString.split("\n").filter(el => el.startsWith("ip") || el.startsWith("uag")).join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 6):

How about converting it into JSON and then accessing it.

```js
async function getCloudflareJSON(){
let data = await fetch('https://1.1.1.1/cdn-cgi/trace').then(res=>res.text())
let arr = data.trim().split('\n').map(e=>e.split('='))
return Object.fromEntries(arr)
}

getCloudflareJSON().then(console.log)
```

**Output:**

```js
{fl: "202f225", h: "1.1.1.1", ip: "47.37.137.777", ts: "1625581799.09", visit_scheme: "https", …}
```

**Reference:**
[Link1](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/cloudflare-trace-api/issues/3#issue-937962112)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one and it worked

```js
fetch('https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data.match(/ip=(\S+)/)[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this plain text data in array of objects, here is the logic:
`

```js
      const data = `fl=47f54
      h=www.cloudflare.com
      ip=11.111.11.11
      ts=1597428248.652
      visit_scheme=https
      uag=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)        Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
      colo=OH
      http=http/2
      loc=US
      tls=TLSv1.3
      sni=plaintext
      warp=off`;

      data.split('\n').map((item)=>{
      let b = {};
      const c = item.split('=');
      b[c[0]]=c[1]
      return b;
      })
```

`